# REST: Handling computed and related resource properties

Tags: api, mongodb, rest, mongoose

Let's say I have a Wordpress-like blogging system with resources consisting of User, Post and Comment resources.  Each of these resources is stored as a separate collection in a MongoDB database, and they are related to one another through ObjectID-valued fields.  Specifically: a Post has an `author` field containing the ObjectID of its related User resource, and a Comment has an `author` field for the related user and a `relatedPost` field for the ObjectID of the post to which the comment applies.

Clearly, there are many instances where separately retrieving these resources will be inefficient.  An example is displaying a particular Post resource client-side: ideally the name of that post's author should be displayed alongside the post title and body, but the Post document itself only contains the ObjectID of the related User document.

The simple solution is to retrieve these related properties on the server side and send additional data to the client.  While that's a good solution for something simple like the blog I'm describing, it raises a few issues for more complicated systems.  Specifically:

- If `GET /api/posts/#{postID}` returns a JSON object with properties that are not really properties of the given Post document, how can I inform the client of this?
- As an extension of the first issue: how can the client be informed that attempting to update a given field of that document with a `POST` to the same URI will not actually update the resource?
- Would it be more appropriate for `GET /api/posts/#{postID}` to only return the properties really present on that document, with a secondary URI like `/api/posts/#{postID}/withauthor` returning the document plus related information?

More concretely, let's say these resources are defined by the following Mongoose.js-style schemas:

```
User: {
  _id: ObjectID,
  username: String,
  name: {
    first: String,
    last: String
  }
}

Post: {
  _id: ObjectID,
  author: ObjectID,
  title: String,
  body: String,
  timestamp: Date
}

Comment: {
  _id: ObjectID,
  author: ObjectID,
  relatedPost: ObjectID,
  title: String,
  body: String,
  timestamp: Date
}
```

I want a `GET`-able resource that returns a full representation of a Post document as well as the first and last name of the related author, so something like this:

```
request: GET /api/posts/529635f828ab08e00d000084

response: {
  _id: "529635f828ab08e00d000084",
  title: "A Post",
  body: "It turns out I have very little to say.",
  author: {
    _id: "928495a321cf09c11d198001",
    name: {
      first: "John",
      last: "Smith"
    }
  }
```

I don't want to lead the client to believe that updating `author.name.first` and `POST`-ing the JSON to the same URI is going to have any effect on the document's `author` attribute on the backend.  Only an update to `author._id` should change the document's author.  Is there a common "RESTful" approach to this?

I know there's no single correct answer here, and the simple approach I described earlier will work for this particular problem.  But I'm curious as to how others have approached the issue in more complicated APIs.

(Note: there is a strong possibility that I'm overthinking this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common question when designing RESTful Services. And the best way I found to handling this is by documenting your RESTful Services correctly (maybe even provide a playground environment for the client to try out the apis). Here's how I will handle your usecase.

I will have a GET request for a given blog_post which will ONLY return the blog_post entity

> GET /api/posts/abcd1234

which returns the basic blog_post with author id.

now, I will have a variation to the same GET request as this:

> GET /api/posts/abcd1234?comments=true&authors=true&startIndex=0&offset=10&sortDirection=Ascending&sortBy=comment_date

The above api will return the post with author and the list of comments with authors with some other filters related to pagination etc. The client can use any permutation combination they like on this api filters and depending on the filter, you return the data back, something along the lines of

> blog_post:{
>
> your normal blog_post fields here ...
>
> full author object here ...
>
> comments: [{
>
> list of comments (with author for each comment and applied filter) here ...
>
> }]
>
> }

This will also maintain your RESTful approach for other requests on the same blog_post. For example, updating the author of the blog_post

> POST /api/posts/abcd1234

will still only update the authorId in the blog_post because the way you will document this POST request is just letting the client know that the only thing you expect here is a blog_post object with id, title, body an authorId and every other field that they might sent to you as a part of the blog_post request will be discarded/ignored.

How a client will consume your REST services, very heavily depends on how well have you documented your REST services.